# $p^{th}$ root of an analytic function $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that a function f is analytic and free of zeroes in a domain $D$.  Under the assumption that a branch $g$ of the $p^{th}$-root of $f$ exists in $D$, show that there are exactly $p$ distinct branches of the $p^{th}$-root of $f$ in $D$ each having the form $cg$ for some $p^{th}$-root of unity $c$.

How would I start this proof?  I'm aware that if $g$ is a branch of the $p^{th}$ root function, then each branch has the form $cg$ where $c$ is a root of unity.

Answer (score 1):

If $h(z)$ is another $p$-th root then for each $z$ you have $h(z) = e^{2\pi i k\over p} g(z)$ for some $k$ since they have to have the same $p$th power. So the issue is why the same $k$ works for all $z$. For a given $k$ the set $D_k = \{z \in D: h(z) = e^{2\pi i k\over p} g(z)\}$ is closed so you have $D$ as a union of finitely many closed sets. Since $D$ is connected all but one of them are empty.

Comment: Why would all but one of them be empty?

Comment: A connected set can't be written as the union of two disjoint closed sets. So if $D_{k_1}$ and some other $D_{k}$ are nonempty you could write $D = D_{k_1} \cup (\cup_{k \neq k_1} D_k)$ in this way